# How do I open Gmail in Firefox on Scientific Linux?

Tags: firefox, scientific-linux, gmail

I can access every website in my browser except Gmail.

When I try to open it in the browser it just keeps searching and never gets anywhere.

I've tried deleting my history, cookies and cache and restarting the laptop but to no avail.

I can't find any other advice online.

Comment: `ping gmail.com` and `traceroute gmail.com`, what do they return?

Comment: (I removed the middle to save characters)traceroute gmail.com traceroute to gmail.com (216.58.198.69), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)  2.841 ms  2.829 ms  2.852 ms
 2  95-44-20-1-dynamic.agg2.csr.dbc-mgr.eircom.net (95.44.20.1)  16.335 ms  18.047 ms  27.657 ms
10  216.239.42.240 (216.239.42.240)  20.474 ms 216.239.42.238 (216.239.42.238)  22.248 ms  21.046 ms
11  64.233.174.27 (64.233.174.27)  18.981 ms  18.307 ms  18.164 ms
12  dub08s02-in-f5.1e100.net (216.58.198.69)  17.516 ms  16.601 ms  18.595 ms

Comment: (This doesn't come to a stop)$ ping gmail.com
PING gmail.com (209.85.203.18) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dh-in-f18.1e100.net (209.85.203.18): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=15.8 ms
64 bytes from dh-in-f18.1e100.net (209.85.203.18): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=16.8 ms
64 bytes from dh-in-f18.1e100.net (209.85.203.18): icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=15.5 ms
64 bytes from dh-in-f18.1e100.net (209.85.203.18): icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=16.3 ms
64 bytes from dh-in-f18.1e100.net (209.85.203.18): icmp_seq=5 ttl=47 time=15.8 ms
64 bytes from dh-in-f18.1e100.net (209.85.203.18): icmp_seq=6 ttl=47 time=15.7 ms